# Multiply tuple elements if the first element in a tuple matches else ignore

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples, multiplication

I have a list of tuples like below

```
[(0, 33), (3, 26), (4, 95), (0, 28), (1, 12), (2, 3), (4, 69)]
```

I want to multiply the second elements of the tuple IF the first element matches (once or more); if not I ignore the tuple. So, the output should be

```
33 * 28 + 95 * 69 = 7479
```

Currently, I am doing the following :

1. Using a counter to check the existence of the first elements of the tuple.
2. Iterate over the collection to see if there exist 1-element tuples or more; ignore the 1-element ones
3. Iteratively add the non 1-element tuples to a dictionary and update multiply
4. Use the `sum` function over the `values` of the dictionary

I wonder if there's a pythonic way to reduce this. I am pretty sure I am complicating matters here.

Comment: The Pythonic way would probably be along the lines of: have a dict whose keys are the first elements, and walk along the whole list only once, updating the dictionary.  Each value contains information like "was it seen more than one" and "here's the product of these items so far".

Comment: I wonder if something like `ifilter` can help.

Comment: In your place, I'd write the algo as I described above step by step, and not worry about some itertools function.

Answer (score 0):

I will program something like this

```
collection = [(0, 33), (3, 26), (4, 95), (0, 28), (1, 12), (2, 3), (4, 69)]
output = 0
for elem in collection:
    collection.remove(elem)
    new_collection = collection
    part_output = 0
    for new_elem in new_collection:
        if elem[0] == new_elem[0]:
            part_output = (part_output * new_elem[1]) if part_output != 0 else (elem[1] * new_elem[1])
            collection.remove(new_elem)
    output = output + part_output

print output
```

The tuple-list is iterated only once and elements are removed as those are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Surprised there was no good answer to this question...
Here's my take:

```
test = [(0, 33), (3, 26), (4, 95), (0, 28), (1, 12), (2, 3), (4, 69)]
unique_keys = set([pair[0] for pair in test]) #{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
grouped_by_key = [[el[1] for el in test if el[0] == key] for key in unique_keys] # [[33, 28], [12], [3], [26], [95, 69]]
grouped_by_key = filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1,grouped_by_key) # [[33, 28], [95, 69]]

add = lambda x, y : x+y
mul = lambda x, y : x*y
# Alternatively:
# from operator import add, mul

out = reduce(add, map(lambda x: reduce(mul, x), grouped_by_key))  #7479
```

Comment: This doesn't run.  Besides missing comment characters, `xx` is undefined.  Also, the consensus seems to be the answer is 7479, not 7476

Comment: Fixed the xx bit which was a typo after renaming variables. Also the result I am getting is correct...just manually pasted wrongly from console! Thanks for spotting that

Comment: In the second line you are using three concepts `set` `map` and `lambda` to get the unique keys, why not `set([pair[0] for pair in test])` instead ? list comprehension and dict comprehension come quite handy.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `reduce` and `mul` to get the product of a list once I have split your the tuple by keys:

```
test = [(0, 33), (3, 26), (4, 95), (0, 28), (1, 12), (2, 3), (4, 69)]
grouped_by_key = {pair[0] : [] for pair in test} #Initialize dict to hold items
tmp = [grouped_by_key[pair[0]].append(pair[1]) for pair in test] #Add items in lists by keys
```

Now import some stuff:

```
from functools import reduce #reduces iterables
from operator import mul #helps doing multiply for a list
```

Now use the imported functions to get desired result:

```
sum([reduce(mul,v,1) for v in grouped_by_key.values() if len(v) > 1])
7479
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd throw a `defaultdict` in the mix to simplify combining the matches.  I've also included code to produce the equation itself which can be commented out:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import mul

pairs = [(0, 33), (3, 26), (4, 95), (0, 28), (1, 12), (2, 3), (4, 69)]

table = defaultdict(list)

for key, value in pairs:
    table[key].append(value)

result = 0
equation = []

for value in table.values():
    if len(value) > 1:
        equation.append(' * '.join(map(str, value)))
        result += reduce(mul, value)

print ' + '.join(equation), '=', result
```

**OUTPUT**

```
33 * 28 + 95 * 69 = 7479
```